# Python Server running as a Windows Service doens't accept connexion

Tags: python, windows, sockets, service, tcp

Most of all, my question is pretty similar to the following : [Cannot access Python server running as Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833062/cannot-access-python-server-running-as-windows-service). I tried the solution but it doesn't solve my problem.

I was able to connect a client and a server by using the Python Socket Tutorial :

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()


# Echo client program
import socket

HOST = 'daring.cwi.nl'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

and It worked like a charm, then I coded the following Windows Service :

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import logging
import sys


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "PySvc"
    _svc_display_name_ = "PySvc"
    _svc_description_  = "PySvc"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)  
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)  

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))

        logging.basicConfig(filename='C:/test.log',
                            level   =logging.DEBUG, 
                            format  ='%(asctime)s %(message)s', 
                            filemode='w')

        rc = None  

        self.HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning the local host
        self.PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port

        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.s.bind((self.HOST, self.PORT))
        logging.debug("BIND")

        self.s.listen(1)
        logging.debug("LISTENED")

        self.conn, self.addr = self.s.accept()
        logging.debug("ACCEPT")
        logging.debug("connected to " + str(self.addr))

        self.s.setblocking(1)
        logging.debug("set blocking")

        # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping  
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:  
            # block for 5 seconds and listen for a stop event  
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)  

        self.main()

def main(self):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

But the connexion is never accepted by the service. the log contains :

```
2018-03-19 16:37:48,967 BIND
2018-03-19 16:37:48,967 LISTENED
```

If I do a netstat :

```
NETSTAT -an | find /i "listening"
```

I find the following line, which show that the server is listening :

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:50007          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Can someone explain me why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Obvious-ish question: are you trying to connect to the service with (for example) the `Echo client program` you show? If so, are you getting any error messages from that? If you aren't trying to connect, the service will sit there listening until the end of time.

Comment: @msw Yes I use the same echo client I show, it ends up with a timeout error

Comment: then I would suspect the permissions issues cited in the answer you referred to. I am the opposite of a windows guru.

Comment: That's what I suspect too :/ there is some stuffs I need to try before goes to this conclusion

Comment: check the permissions on the firewall port

Comment: @riki  But in these I should not be able to connect the two little script above the service one, right ?

Comment: @snoobdogg try follow this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/Integralist/3f004c3594bbf8431c15ed6db15809ae

Comment: @riki yes you were right, a firewall rule was simply missing